# Populate an array with a number of elements per row based on user submission

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form with 3 fields (select fields with values from 1-5).

> Field 1: Rooms
> Field 2: Adults
> Field 3: Childs

I need to translate the response from form into php array:

If I select 1 room and 2 adults:

```
$rooms[] = array(
    array("paxType" => "Adult"),
    array("paxType" => "Adult")
);
```

I use the below code

```
$AdultsNO = intval($_POST["AdultsNO"]);
$RoomsNO= intval($_POST["RoomsNO"]);
$rooms = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < $RoomsNO; $x++) {
if ( count($RoomsNO) > 0)
    array_push($rooms,array("paxType" => "Adult"));
}
```

But it is returning the response an adult on each room:

For example:

- if I select `1` room and `2` adults, I get:

  `1` room with `1` adult
- if I select `2` room and `4` adults, I get

  `2` rooms, each with only `1` adult

Or to make it easier:
Please advise me how to create a rule as below: ( count if two or more conditions are true

```
if ( count($RoomsNO) = 1) and ( count($Adults) = 1)
        array_push($rooms,array("paxType" => "Adult"));

and

if ( count($RoomsNO) = 1) and ( count($Adults) = 2)
    array_push($rooms,array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"));

and

if ( count($RoomsNO) = 2) and ( count($Adults) = 4)
    array_push($rooms,array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"));
    array_push($rooms,array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"));
```

Comment: It´s a bad idea to use the same variable name with only differing case. That's very confusing.

Comment: PHP isn't case-insensitive; that would be managable. PHP is PART case-insensitive, and part case-sensitive. These ARE two different variables, because var names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Lots of issues in this small piece of code. What is the expected `print_r` result?

Comment: Please go to http://bookingassist.ro/test/teste.php and perform a search, eneter Barcelona in the city field.

Comment: @Raptor While the variable names are case-sensitive, the function names are case-insensitive. Be precise if you say, Epic Fail. Anyway, very unreadable as Erik sad.

Comment: This question does not have a great [mcve].  We don't know how children are meant to be distributed.  Once calculating the max number of adults per room (dividing the total adults by the total rooms), you can push elements into `$rooms` and decrement the total adult count.  This question Needs Clarity.